# How to add a view to SceneKit?

Tags: swift, scenekit

I am very new to Swift and currently coding a minigolf game. 
However, the player can hit the ball n times.

How do I make a simple view which should show how many hits the player has left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want something like this:

First of all, i recommend you to create a function to call when the game is restarted, there you can reset the scene, reset the player moves, etc...

You may do this like:

```
func restart(){
//Everything you need to restart the game
}
```

To call it later you just have to:

```
restart()
```

Ok, let's go to what you asked now:
declare a Int variable that contains the number of moves that the player has:

```
var playerMoves = 10 //Whatever number you want
```

Ok, you have a variable that contains the number of moves, now you have to show this on your scene, to do this, create an SKLabelNode:

```
let moveLabel = SKLabelNode()
```

Now, set the label text to be equal your playerMoves, set the position, the zPosition, the font, whatever you want:

```
moveLabel.text = "\(playerMoves)" //add this line to restart function that i mentioned and also set the variable playerMoves to "n" again.
moveLabel.position = ....
moveLabel.fontSize = ....
moveLabel.zPosition = ... //A number higher than any other zPosition
addChild(moveLabel) //Don't forget to add the label to scene!
```

Thats it! And now you have to update the playerMoves every time the player moves, to do this i'm assuming you are controlling somehow when the player moves (using update function, touches began, created a function, etc....)

so...when the player take one move:

```
playerMoves -= 1 
moveLabel.text = "\(playerMoves)"
```

THATS IT!!! :) HOPE IT HELPS!

Comment: If its that what you want (show the player moves left on the screen), thats what you have to do, you dont need to create a view or anything like this...

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to go about it. the most common way would be to overlay a spritekit scene over the scenekit scene. in the spritekit scene you can have a label element that you update

the code might look something like

```
let overlay = SKScene(fileNamed: "yourspritekitscene.sks")
yourScnView.overlaySKScene = menuOverlay
```

you can also assign a spritekit scene as a texture on a 3D object in your scene. or you can can make the numbers a texture you swap as you count down.